# How to find the exact value of the integral $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^{2n+1} x}{x^{2}} d x$, where $n$ is a natural number?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Let $I(m,n):=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^{m} x}{x^{n}} d x$, where $0<n\leq m.$

A month ago, I had found,in my [essay](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4271756/732917), that when $m$ and $n$ are of the same parity and  $2\leq n\leq m,$
$$\boxed{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{m}x}{x^{n}}dx=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{m-n}{2}} \pi}{2^{m}(n-1) !} \sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m-1}{2}\right\rfloor}(-1)^{k}\left(\begin{array}{l}
m \\
k
\end{array}\right)(m-2 k)^{n-1}},
$$

In other words, $I(m,n) =\dfrac{a\pi}{b}$ for some natural numbers $a$ and $b$.

However, when $m$ and $n$ are of different parity, $$I(m,n) =\dfrac{a}{b}ln(\dfrac{c}{d})$$ for some natural numbers $a, b, c $ and $d$.

Then I started to investigate whether there is a formula for $I(m,n)$ of different parity.

Started from easy, I am going to find, by [Frullani’s Integral Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral)), a formula for, $$I(2n+1,2)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^{2n+1} x}{x^{2}} d x
=\frac{2 n+1}{2^{2 n}(-1)^{n-1}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 n-1 \\
k
\end{array}\right) \ln \left|\frac{2 n+1-2 k}{2 n-3-2 k}\right|.
$$
Proof:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(2 n+1,2) &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin ^{2 n+1} x d\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right) \\
&\stackrel{IBP}{=} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(2 n+1) \sin ^{2 n} x \cos x}{x} d x \\
&=(2 n+1) \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin 2 x}{2 x} \cdot \sin ^{2 n-1} x d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Expressing $\sin^{2n-1}x$ as a linear combination of $\sin(2n-1-2k)$ yields
$$\begin{array}{l} \\ \displaystyle \quad I(2n+1,2)\\ \displaystyle =\frac{2 n+1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin 2 x}{x} \left[\frac{1}{2^{2 n-2}(-1)^{n-1}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k} \left(\begin{array}{c}
2 n-1 \\
k
\end{array}\right)\sin (2 n-1-2 k) x \right]dx\\
\displaystyle =\frac{2 n+1}{2^{2 n-1}(-1)^{n-1}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 n-1 \\
k
\end{array}\right)\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin 2 x \sin (2 n-1-2 k)x}{x} d x \\
=\displaystyle \frac{2 n+1}{2^{2 n}(-1)^{n-1}} \frac{n-1}{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 n-1 \\
k
\end{array}\right) \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (2 n-3-2 k) x-\cos (2 n+1-2k)x}{x} dx\\
\displaystyle =\frac{2 n+1}{2^{2 n}(-1)^{n-1}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 n-1 \\
k
\end{array}\right) \ln \left|\frac{2 n+1-2 k}{2 n-3-2 k}\right|\quad \blacksquare
\end{array}$$(The last step using [Frullani’s Integral Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral))

For examples:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^{5} x}{x^{2}} d x &=\frac{-5}{16}\left[\left(\begin{array}{c}
3 \\
0
\end{array}\right) \ln 5-\left(\begin{array}{l}
3 \\
1
\end{array}\right) \ln 3\right]=\frac{5}{16} \ln \frac{27}{5}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^{7} x}{x^{2}} d x=\frac{7}{64}\left[\left(\begin{array}{l}
5 \\
0
\end{array}\right) \ln \left(\frac{7}{3}\right)-\left(\begin{array}{c}
5 \\
1
\end{array}\right) \ln \left(\frac{5}{1}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{l}
5 \\
2
\end{array}\right) \ln \left(\frac{3}{1}\right)\right]= \frac{7}{64} \ln \left(\frac{137781}{3125}\right)
$$
Eureka! I succeeded to find a formula for $I(2n+1,2)$.  I believe that we can find a reduction formula and use Induction to prove that when $m$ and $n$ are of different parity, $$I(m,n) =\dfrac{a}{b}\ln(\dfrac{c}{d})$$
However, it is difficult to find a general formula for $I(m,n)$ of ***different parity***.

Please give me opinions to go further.  Thank you very much!

Comment: There is a fully general result. See [mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html) identity 37. There should be a reference as well.

Comment: Use [Lobachevsky's Integral Formula](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.2653) and then [Wallis Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals?wprov=sfla1).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable references.